# Why does sudo ask for a password in terminal?

Tags: terminal, sudo

Why does `sudo` ask for a password when one can `sudo su` without a password and perform the same commands? Is there a way to make sudo not ask for a password when you're logged in as the an admin anyway?

Comment: You can remove the password by modifying your `sudoers` file. I don't remember the details, but `man sudoers` and `man visudo` will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sudo su` asks for a password on my system. Did you run another `sudo` command before the `sudo su`? Once you've run `sudo` and entered your password, it doesn't require a password again for a period of time.

Comment: Where "a period of time" is 5 minutes IIRC.

Comment: @JasonSalaz That sounds about right. I didn't want to look it up, and the exact time didn't seem all that relevant.

Comment: @JasonSalaz: Yes, by default. See the entry `timestamp_timeout` in the `sudoers` manual page.

Comment: I tried opening a new terminal window before I posted the question but it appears sudoing the password goes across windows

Comment: Indeed, it's system-wide.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, it's system-wide until some recent version of sudo. Some time in the last few months, my Linux system's sudo behavior changes, and the 5 minute sudo timeout is PER SHELL. Meaning if I run a command via sudo, open a new tab and run another command via sudo, I have to re-auth on the second tab, but can go back to the first one and keep using sudo within the timeout. Just don't be surprised if/when it makes it's way to OS X :).

Comment: @JasonSalaz That makes a lot of sense. I'm surprised that didn't make it in until now.

Answer (score 5):

You can just modify following lines in /etc/sudoers :

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

to

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo will *always* want a password once, but just set a crazy long timeout -- and note that it is specified in minutes:

Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=60

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question.

Comment: @JasonSalaz In my opinoon the hint for setting a timeout is not a full answer, but helpful for the second question "Is there a way to make sudo not ask for a password...?"