# Enable sudo without a password on MacOS

Tags: password, macos, sudo

## My Problem

I would like to be able to run `sudo` commands on [MacOS Sierra 10.12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra) without having to type a password.

## What have I tried

I've read the following:

- [Why does sudo ask for a password in terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53065/why-does-sudo-ask-for-a-password-in-terminal)
- [allow sudo to another user without password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82438/allow-sudo-to-another-user-without-password)
- [Use sudo Without a Password on Your Mac](https://romkey.com/2008/11/08/use-sudo-without-a-password-on-your-mac/)

And changed the relevant part of my `/etc/sudoers` file to:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
adamatan ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

My local user id (`whoami`) is `adamatan`.

I'm still being asked to type a password every few minutes when calling `sudo`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does sudo -i work on Sierra? In El Cap it will switch you to root context and run login resource files for that session. (Will still need to be sudoers, so earlier effort not wasted).

Comment: Works, but how does it solve the problem?

Comment: I just recently upgraded to Sierra and ran into this. The default `/etc/sudoers` file has changed fairly  radically from El Cap. There I just dropped a one line config file into the sudoers.d directory and it "just worked". Seems things have changed. I'll report back if I get anymore info.

Comment: Maybe just execute one of the macOS root permissions exploits instead ;)

Comment: That defeats the whole point of sudo

Comment: I know this question is old but to anyone who is reading this:  NEVER ENABLE `sudo` WITHOUT PASSWORD.  This is probably the single most dangerous thing a person can ever do to their computer.  Why is no one moderating here?  IMHO this question and all answers below should include a short caveat saying something like "Do this at your own risk, this will make your computer extremely vulnerable to hacking and viruses."

Comment: @ed9w2in6 It's common to enable sudo access without a password for service accounts that is used to maintain a fleet of computers. For example, CI/CD systems may install dependencies on macOS build agents, and configuration management systems may run commands to "patch" the operating system.

Comment: @ed9w2in6 - it all depends on what that access can reach and what other layers of security are applied. There's always a why for everything. You still have to get into the other non-sudo user to get in anyway, and the machine may be on an internal network. Security is always a trade-off and a combination of things. It's just not true to make a blanket statement that you should never enable sudo without password. I do it routinely. Also, everyone should be using everything on stack exchange at their own risk. There's no guarantees for anything here.

Comment: Well I had never pictured macOS to be used as an CI/CD system, which can be one good use case of a no password sudo.  I agree that NEVER is indeed a strong word, SHOULD is probably a better choice of word.  In such cases it is also probably better to only whitelist certain commands.

Answer (score 103):

Open a terminal, run `sudo visudo`

Edit the line:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

To say:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Now, you should now be able to run `sudo` without password.

Comment: reboot it not really needed

Comment: the key is to use `sudo visudo` instead of `sudo vi /etc/sudoers` -- especially now with the read-only root filesystem in MacOS 10.15.

Comment: I'm getting "visudo: /etc/sudoers: Operation not permitted" when running sudo visudo

Comment: you probably need to open a new terminal after that

Comment: Works on my Mac Pro 2021. Monterey Ver 12.4

Answer (score 20):

Better not to edit `/etc/sudoers` directly. 
Instead, the `/etc/sudoers` file does include a line:

```
## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

So better simply add an empty file under `/private/etc/sudoers.d/mysudo` and use `visudo` to fill it with a content like:

```
mylogin            ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Remember to *always* run `sudo visudo` after creating the empty file under `/private/etc/sudoers.d/` so that visudo also checks for syntax on that file, or else you might end up with a broken sudo configuration and the inability to run `visudo` to fix it.

You have been warned

Comment: I was forced to do this on latest OS of mac, it wouldn't let me update sudoers file, kept saying invalid. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

stens ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL # my userid is stens
```

Answer (score 4):

Execute the terminal whoami command to find your username (also known as ldapname).

```
> whoami
```

Chase that with executing the command below (be comfortable using VI/VIM before proceeding).

```
> sudo visudo -f /private/etc/sudoers.d/sudogo
```

NOTE1: The -f syntax will permit you to specify an alternate sudoers file location. With this option, visudo will edit (or check) the sudoers file of your choice, instead of the default, /etc/sudoers. The lock file used is the specified sudoers file with ".tmp" appended to it. In check-only mode only, the argument to -f may be -, indicating that sudoers will be read from the standard input.

NOTE2/WARNING: You could have created a file named "nopw" in place of sudogo. However, hackers are slick and will look for the letters "PW" (abbreviation for password). Feel free to change "sudogo" to something different, logical, and safe. Be aware that an extension was not added to the end of the file; It is not required.

An example is posted below. Activate insert mode with i, copy both lines posted below into the blank file. Substitute INSERT_USERNAME for ldapname. Hit escape, save and quit the file with :wq from command mode.

```
# user(s) below can can run any script on this machine
INSERT_USERNAME        ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Execute sudo visudo (-f and path omitted) one final time. The command will open the sudoers file and check the changes. Proceed to type :q! to exit /etc/sudoers without saving changes.

```
> sudo visudo
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting NOPASSWD on the root user. In `/etc/sudoers`

```
root            ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```