# How to enter a Mac system password in Terminal if you don't have one

Tags: terminal, password

I am trying Terminal for the first time.  I have entered a properly coded command and Terminal is asking for a password.  I don't have a Mac system password, so I have pressed Enter, but that doesn't work.  Have tried with my Apple ID, again, no joy.  Suggestions?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257813/enable-sudo-without-a-password-on-macos tbh, I'm not sure how you can even create an admin account without a password.

Answer (score 1):

If you run a command with `sudo` that's like asking for Administrative privileges to ensure you know what you're doing.

The "system" password it refers to is the same password you use when logging into your Mac.

If this password does not work, you likely only have a Standard user account.

Also, when copying terminal commands from the internet, please make sure you know what they are doing before running them :)

Comment: Interesting.  I am listed in Users & Groups as the administrator.  It has always been my home computer, single user.  But I do not have a "system" password, never have had.  But I take your comment about using terminal commands, so will reconsider that action.  Thanks.

Comment: @EJay did you try using the same password that you use when logging into your Mac? You can easily test it will work by running a command like:

`sudo touch /Users/Shared/test.txt`

This will create an empty file in /Users/Shared called test.txt and should prompt you for a password. If it creates successfully, you know that you have the right privileges and password.